Serial reading not give expected output
I made a code reading RPi by serial from pressure sensor. Somehow my code reading raw data from serial sensor but my while loop does not work and I'm betting blank screen.
What I'm doing wrong? Whole code below:
import serial
import sys
import time

gauge = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/serial0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout = 1
    )

while(True):
    while(True):
        input_string = list(gauge.read(2)) #watch for two magic bytes
        if(input_string[0] == 7 and input_string[1] == 5):
            input_string += list(gauge.read(9-2)) #append the rest of the data
            if((sum(input_string[1:8]) % 256) == input_string[8]): #compute checksum
                break

    gauge_value = 10.0**((input_string[4] * 256.0 + input_string[5]) / 4000.0 - 12.5)
    if(len(sys.argv) > 2):
        print("mBar: {} Pa: {} Status: {} ({}) Error: {} ({})".format(gauge_value,gauge_value*100000.0,
                                                        input_string[2],bin(input_string[2]),
                                                        input_string[3],bin(input_string[3])))
    else:
        print("{},{}".format(time.time(), gauge_value))

Here is code reading raw data:
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/serial0',#Replace ttyUSB0 with ttyAMA0 for Pi1,Pi2,Pi0
        baudrate = 9600,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout=1
)

while 1:
        x=ser.readline()
        print (x)

Raw data as below:
'\n'
b'\x8e\x07\x05@\x08\xbcI(!\xfe\x15A\x00\xec\x1c\x00\x8d\xbc\x87\x1c\x1c\xf4!\x00\n'
b'\x1c\x07\x05\x00\x00\xec\x95\x94\xb5\xf8\x144\x15\xec\x0e\x00\n'
b'\t\x07\x05 \x88n8H$\xa8\x1c\x00\xec\x03\x00\xca{\x07\x15\x90\xb0\xb5?\n'
b'\xf3P\x10\x00\xeb\xb6\x08\x95\xbc(\x1c\x1c\xb4\xfa\x00\n'

So my guess is I made something wrong in while loop.
For clarification below message format from device manual:


You are probably getting a blank screen because the inner while loop never hits the break. What does the device documentation say the format of the message is?

@001 added screen from manual.

@001 You may be right, code is reading 2 bytes looking for value 7 and 5 and go to checksum and if checksum. If something is wromg with  transer loop may never go to external if-else. Do you think it would be better to use readline instead of read. I'm quite new and not really know how from readline catch bit 4 and 5 which give me data I'm interested.

I would not use readline. That reads all bytes up until a newline char - and there's no guarantee your data will have a newline char. I would read one byte at a time to find the start of message. For ex: read 1 byte. If it is a 7, read 1 byte. If it is a 5, read 7 bytes...

The values in the data dump do not match what you would expect from the doc. Every 9th byte should be 0x7 followed by 0x5, but that's not the case here.

I discovered line input_string = list(gauge.read(2)) read only 2 values at time and stop. How to make code reading till get  detect correct values of bit 0 and 1?

With the example data you have posted in the question, the break statement is never being hit because the calculated checksums are not as expected. For packets that start with 7 and 5, the sensor type is not as expected either. If you ignore those issues then one of the readings is reporting a BA error. I think you need to simplify your while loops to separate out the different methods of failure.

Yeah, I have diagnosed sensor of gauge is damaged and need replacement. Believe this is reason why error byte giving different values.

You appear to always be looking for a payload of 9 bytes so it might useful to read the serial connection one byte at a time and store it in a Python deque.
Then after each read check the 9 bytes stored in the deque to see if there is the correct/expected sequence of bytes.
The data you posted in your question did not seem consistent so I extended it using the following example from the manual:

the code appears to give the correct answer.
I don't have the sensor so I substituted the serial port with a Python Binary I/O stream with the example data.
This is the code I used to mock the data coming from the sensor and use structure for the processing of the incoming data:
from collections import deque
from enum import Enum
import io


PKT_SIZE = 9

# gauge = serial.Serial(
#     port = '/dev/serial0',
#     baudrate = 9600,
#     parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
#     stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
#     bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
#     timeout = 1000
#     )

gauge = io.BytesIO((
    b"\n\x8e"
    b"\x07\x05@\x08\xbcI(!\xfe"
    b"\x15A\x00\xec\x1c\x00\x8d\xbc\x87\x1c\x1c\xf4!\x00\n\x1c"
    b"\x07\x05\x00\x00\xec\x95\x94\xb5\xf8"
    b"\x144\x15\xec\x0e\x00\n\t"
    b"\x07\x05 \x88n8H$\xa8"
    b"\x1c\x00\xec\x03\x00\xca{"
    b"\x07\x15\x90\xb0\xb5?\n\xf3P"
    b"\x10\x00\xeb\xb6\x08\x95\xbc(\x1c\x1c\xb4\xfa\x00\n"
    b"\x07\x05\x00\x00\xf2\x30\x14\x0a\x45"
))


class Units(Enum):
    MBAR = 0
    TORR = 1
    PA = 2
    UNUSED = 3


class ErrorCodes(Enum):
    NO_ERROR = 0
    PIRANI_ADJ_ERROR = 5
    BA_ERROR = 8
    PIRANI_ERROR = 9


def checksum_ok(sensor_data):
    calc_sum = sum(list(sensor_data)[1:8]) & 0xff
    return calc_sum == sensor_data[8]


def process_read(sensor_data):
    # print(sensor_data)
    (
        data_len,
        page_num,
        status,
        error,
        hi_byte,
        lo_byte,
        version,
        sen_type,
        check_sum,
    ) = sensor_data
    if all(
        (
            data_len == 7,
            page_num == 5,
            sen_type == 10
        )
    ):
        if not checksum_ok(sensor_data):
            print("ERROR: Failed checksum")
            return None
        # print(f"{status:08b}")
        measurement = hi_byte << 8 | lo_byte
        units_status = get_units(status)
        error_status = get_error_status(error)
        if error_status != ErrorCodes.NO_ERROR:
            print(f"ERROR: {error_status}")
        gauge_value = calc_gauge_value(measurement, units_status)
        return gauge_value
    return None


def get_units(status_byte):
    return Units(status_byte >> 4 & 0x03)


def get_error_status(error_byte):
    return ErrorCodes(error_byte >> 4 & 0x0f)


def calc_gauge_value(measurement, units_status):
    if units_status == Units.MBAR:
        gauge_value = 10.0 ** (measurement / 4000.0 - 12.5)
    elif units_status == Units.TORR:
        gauge_value = 10.0 ** (measurement / 4000.0 - 12.625)
    elif units_status == Units.PA:
        gauge_value = 10.0 ** (measurement / 4000.0 - 10.5)
    else:
        print("ERROR: invalid units setting")
        gauge_value = None
    return gauge_value


def main():
    msg = deque([0] * PKT_SIZE, PKT_SIZE)
    while True:
        new_byte = gauge.read(1)
        msg.append(int.from_bytes(new_byte, "little", signed=False))
        # print(f'\t{msg}')
        reading = process_read(msg)
        if reading:
            print(f"\tSensor reading: {reading}")
        if sum(msg) == 0:
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I would read 1 byte at a time until you get 0x7 and 0x5. I can't really test this since I don't have the device, so...
# Helper function that does not yield (return) until it has a good message
def next_msg(guage):
    while True:
        # Look for 7,5 combo
        data_len = 0
        page_number = 0
        while data_len != 7 and page_number != 5:
            data_len = page_number
            page_number = guage.read(1)[0]

        # If we are here, we have a valid 7,5 start of message
        payload = guage.read(data_len - 1)
        checksum = guage.read(1)[0]
        if (sum(payload) + page_number) % 255 == checksum:
            yield (payload[0], payload[1], payload[2] * 256 + payload[3], payload[4], payload[5])

for status,error,measurement,version,sensor_type in next_msg(guage):
    # Do something with the data...
    print(status, error, measurement, version, sensor_type)


Side note: Note the lack of parentheses in the if and while statements as well as the spaces after keywords. It's more in line with the Python formatting style.
** Edited the checksum calculation. I did not include the '5' (page number) but I think it is supposed to be there.
** Edit: updated for loop based on OP's answer
# Ignoring status,error,version,sensor_type
for _,_,measurement,_,_ in next_msg(guage):
    measurement = 10.0**(measurement / 4000.0 - 12.5)
    print(measurement)


Thanks @001
I have expanded code to form as below:
import serial
import sys
import time

gauge = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/serial0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout = 1000
    )
    
    
def next_msg(gauge):
    while True:
        # Look for 7,5 combo
        msg_start = [None, None]
        while msg_start != [7, 5]:
            msg_start[0] = msg_start[1]
            msg_start[1] = gauge.read(1)[0]

        # If we are here, we have a valid 7,5 start of message
        payload = gauge.read(6)
        checksum = gauge.read(1)[0]
        if sum(payload) % 255 == checksum:
            yield (payload[0], payload[1], payload[2] * 256 + payload[3], payload[4], payload[5])


for measurement in next_msg(gauge): 
    payload = gauge.read(6)
    measurement = 10.0**((payload[4] * 256.0 + payload[5]) / 4000.0 - 12.5)
    print(measurement)

And got result:
3.162277660168379e-13
9.036494737223004
4.340102636447431e-10
3.7325015779571986
3.162277660168379e-13
4.487453899331332e-10
3.5686174928348136e-13
6.9742899688173485e-12
1.499684835502374e-08

Each number appear with delay 1 second to each other.
Gear is Inficon BPG400 vacuum gauge. This suppose to be pressure values in mbar and doesn't seem to be correct.
Now working on atmospheric pressure so correct value should be around 1000mbar. If I didn't messed up in code I believe it's matter or proper set up or gauge may be damaged.

payload = gauge.read(6) This has already been done in next_msg so you do not need to do it again in the for loop. See my updated answer.

If I do this your way get error payload not defined. Additional topic is sometimes need to wait for measurement up to minute. Have to debug vacuum gauge
